# C Quicksort, ignore first character in a string?

Tags: c, sorting

I'm quick sorting an array of structs, and this struct has a char* called ProcessName. Now I have sorted it alphabetically using Qsort using my compare function, however if ProcessName starts with ( it will not sort correctly.

for example, "(ssh)" should be after "bash" however due to the parentheses being the first character, the parentheses is before bash, when it should only take into account the letter after the parentheses.

Now I have an idea of how this would work, check if the first character is '(' then increment the string, but this ran into some pointer issues.

Here is my compare function

```
int compare(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    const process *first = p1;
    const process *second = p2;
    return strcmp(first->Processname, second->Processname);
}
```

Comment: Is it just `(` that you have to skip over, or any non-letter?

Comment: Any non letter would work, however skipping over ( would be fine for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the first character of either of the strings is `(`. If it is, increment the pointer to skip over it.

```
int compare(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    const process *first = p1;
    char *name1 = first->Processname;
    if (name1[0] == '(') {
        name1++;
    }
    const process *second = p2;
    char *name2 = second->Processname;
    if (name2[0] == '(') {
        name2++;
    }
    return strcmp(name1, name2);
}
```

For a more general way to skip to the first letter, use [`strcspn()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn).

Comment: Thank you! I was trying something very similar to this, worked perfectly

Comment: @Fireboy653: but don't forget malformed input. If you encounter end-of-string `0` while skipping, you'd probably best revert to the original string. At least that way your sorting is guaranteed to be stable.